# Pipeline actions deprecated (Node.js 12)

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, pipeline, roblox, foreman

I'm currently setting up a simple CI pipeline for a project on Github but I've run into a problem. When I run a Selene Lint check, my code does get successfully integrated but I get this warning:

> Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.
> Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: Roblox/setup-foreman@v1

Here is my `ci.yaml`:

```
name: CI Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - main

jobs: 

  lint:
    name: Selene Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - uses: Roblox/setup-foreman@v1
      name: Install Foreman
      with: 
        version: "^1.0.0"
        token: ${{ SECRETS.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Selene Lint
      run: |
        selene ./src
```

Does anyone know how I can set up Foreman using Node.js 16?

Unfortunately, this is my first time setting up a CI Pipeline so I am not to familiar with how to approach this issue.

Comment: 1. https://github.com/Roblox/setup-foreman Report to its authors. 2. Fork and create your own action 3. Switch to an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is still the case in June 2023: [Roblox/setup-foreman PR 39](https://github.com/Roblox/setup-foreman/pull/39/files) did update Node version in Apr. 2023 with their [v2.1 release](https://github.com/Roblox/setup-foreman/releases/tag/v2.1)

Their [`action.yml`](https://github.com/Roblox/setup-foreman/blob/master/action.yml) now include the correct version:

```yaml
name: 'Setup Foreman'
description: 'Install Foreman, a toolchain manager for Roblox projects'
author: 'The Rojo Developers'
inputs:
  version:
    required: false
    description: 'SemVer version of Foreman to install'
  working-directory:
    required: false
    description: 'Working directory to run `foreman install` in'
  token:
    required: true
    description: 'GitHub token from secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN'
runs:
  using: 'node16'
  main: 'dist/index.js'
```